# Regex: Read value between multiple brackets

Tags: java, regex, smarty, gettext, poedit

I currently working on translating a website ([Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)) with Poedit. To get all the text from the .tpl files i'm using regex to get the data between the {t} and {/t}. so an example:

```
{t}Password incorrect, please try again{/t}
```

The regex will read `Password incorrect, please try again` and place it in a .po file. This is all working fine. It goes wrong when it gets a little more advanced.

Sometimes the text between the {t} tags uses a parameter. this looks like this:

```
{t 1=$email|escape 2=$mailbox}No $1 given, please check your $2{/t}
```

This is also working great.

The real problem start when i use brackets inside the parameter like this:

```
{t 1={site info='name'} 2=$mailbox}visit %1 or go to your %2{/t}
```

My regex will close when it sees the first closing brackets so the result will be `2=$mailbox}visit %1 or go to your %2`.

My regex looks like this:

```
\{t.*?\}?[}]([^\{]+)\{\/t\}|\{t\}([^\{]+)\{\/t\}
```

The regex is used inside a java program.

Does anybody has a way to fix this problem?

Comment: The fix is to write a parser to handle nested brackets.  Regex doesn't handle this type of problem very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution I see on this is to normalize the .tpl files. Just use a regex which matches *all* tags something like this one:

```
{[^}]*[^{]*}
```

I had the same issue to solve and it worked pretty good with the normalizing.

The normalizing-method would look like this:

```
final String regex = "\\{[^\\}]*[^\\{]*\\}";

private String normalizeContent(String content) {
    return content.replaceAll(regex, "");
}
```